# llamar un controlador dentro de un test en cakephp

Tags: php

no puedo llamar a un controlador en un test de cakephp2, quiero llamar a un controlador pero usando `App::import` o `App::uses` no me deja, tampoco me deja llamar al `$this->testAction`

¿como podría llamarlo?

lo he utilizado de la siguiente forma:

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Api2Controller');

/**
 * Api2Controller Test Case
 *
 */
class Api2ControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {   
     // public $fixtures = array('Api2Controller.crearDireccion');

    function setUp(){
        parent::setUp();
     $this->Api2 = ClassRegistry::init('Api2Controller');
    }

    function tearDown(){
        parent::tearDown();

    }

    public function testArraySearchRecursive() {
       $this->Api2->mimetodo();
    }
```

pero no me funciona, también he llamado al controlador desde el mismo método por `App::import('Controller', 'Api2Controller')` luego realizo una instancia de el pero me aparece PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Api2Controller' not found

Comment: agrega por favor como usas App::import o tu código! :)

Answer (score 1):

al parecer esta función `ClassRegistry::init` instancia solo los modelos y  `App::uses('Controller', 'Api2Controller');` la estaba utilizando al revés es `App::uses('Api2Controller' ,'Controller')`